# bash script: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I tried to run the code as below and it gets me error: command not found for line 4,5,6. Tried to find similar answers for the questions but I don't know how to figure out the version of the OS of the cluster which Im running this script. Im not sure is there any problem with the first line or the line 4,5,6. Could anyone help?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 02 03 04 05 06 07 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 20 21 22 23 24 25; do
 x=grep $i sphnum.txt |cut -c5-6
 y=grep $i sphnum.txt |cut -c8-9
 z=echo $i'.ala.'$x'.sph '$i'.ala.'$y'.sph'
 echo $z
done
```

Comment: last variable z is for concaternating those strings into a string.

Comment: Replace `x=grep $i sphnum.txt |cut -c5-6` with `x=$(grep $i sphnum.txt |cut -c5-6)`. Similarly for the other two lines.

Comment: You're trying to run a command named (the value of) `$i`. The `$(...)` makes bash run a subcommand. See the "Command Substituion" section of the bash man page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others said you need to capture the output from the commands.

`z=echo foo
-bash: foo: command not found`

is not the same as

`z=$(echo foo)`

In the first one it's equivalent to

`z=echo
foo`

which is not valid as it thinks `foo` is a command.

`z=$(echo foo)` however means to execute `echo foo` and capture the output into `z`.

All of your commands fail to do this.